# How to import package 'Storage' in to Swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, firefox, import, package

I'm currently studying the source code of Firefox-iOS app by creating my own Swift project and typing the code line by line.

In one of the source code files, it imported a packaged named `Storage`

[image]

But I don't think the package `Storage` is part of the apple API and I don't really know how I can import it.

### Edit

Multiple podfiles are present in the project folder

[image]

Comment: does the project have a podfile?

Comment: @HarrySingh I did a search in the original firefox-ios app source code folder, there seem to be multiple podfile in the project. I have uploaded a screenshot of my search

Comment: Looks like it's referring to this https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios/tree/master/Storage

Comment: @HarrySingh thanks for the heads up! problem solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift you dont import other Swift files as they are readily available to use directly.

But you need to import another module. It looks like Storage here is a module inside the firefox-ios app workspace and hence you need to import it before using it.

I looked at the [sourcecode](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios) at Github and it does contain a package named Storage.

[image]

You can read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html) to understand more about Modules and import statement.

Comment: Thanks Sharma for pointing me to the right direction! Problem solved!